# Vim Expression (and Language) sensitive indentation - Possible?

Tags: vim, indentation

Well, I am editing a LaTeX file, but I am not pleased with the default vim indentation.

Let's say I wanted vim do indentate like this:

```
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{A}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
    \end{itemize}
    \section{B}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
    \end{itemize}
    \section{C}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Based in this code, what I basically needed is that it indented in 4 spaces when it found a \begin{*} and to indent in -4 spaces when it found an \end{*}.

Is it possible for me to personalize it?

I read about "indentexpr", which probably would produce what I expect, but I wasn't able to find any examples or guidelines to where to start.

It is important for me to learn HOW to do it, not getting the solution. I need the guidelines to achieve it because probably I'll want to make similar "tunings" in other languages too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *tex.vim* file of *kev* the important parts to adapt are next lines:

1.- These say to no indent lines which contains those strings.

```
if !exists("g:tex_noindent_env")
    let g:tex_noindent_env = 'document\|verbatim'
endif
```

2.- Lines which accomplish this 'if' condition are indented.

```
if line =~ '\\begin{.*}' && line !~ g:tex_noindent_env
    ...
endif
```

3.- Lines which accomplish this 'if' condition are un-indented.

```
if cline =~ '^\s*\\end' && cline !~ g:tex_noindent_env
    ...
endif
```

---

You have two options, comment part `&& line !~ g:tex_noindent_env` or remove `document` from var `g:tex_noindent_env`.

**Option 1 (Put " just before &&)**:

```
if line =~ '\\begin{.*}' "&& line !~ g:tex_noindent_env
```

and

```
if cline =~ '^\s*\\end' "&& cline !~ g:tex_noindent_env
```

**Option 2 (Remove 'document')**:

```
let g:tex_noindent_env = 'verbatim'
```

After this open your file and execute `gg=G`. It should work.

For more information about indent expression, take a look in `syntax` folder of `vim`. Get it with `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` inside `Vim`

Comment: Just what I needed. I was able to modify what I needed for LaTeX, and probably the information I have now will be enough for me to try some things by myself. Thanks! Just one more information: There are indent files located in /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent. Should I make my modifications there or should I put my mods elsewhere?

Comment: @Falassion: (Based in a linux machine) Try copying the file 'tex.vim' to '~/.vim/indent/' and modify it. Vim should read that one before and apply only that indent.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz: Thank you. I try my best to help.

Answer (score 1):

The most important line of code in a `indent` file is:

```
setlocal indentexpr=YourIndentFunc()
```

Within `YourIndentFunc()`, there's a context variable `lnum` which keeps track of current line number.
`YourIndentFunc()` calculates how many white spaces should be insert at start of current line.

[tex.vim : Indent file for TeX](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=218)

Comment: Ok, it is the LaTeX solution, fine. But, as I stated up there, what I want is to learn how to do it, the basics.

Comment: Hmmm.. Allied with Birei's explanation, I'll be able to achieve what I want. Thanks!